# Game Using F# and Silverlight: Avoiding Mutable State

Tags: silverlight, f#

I'm trying to write a game using F# and Silverlight and am struggling a bit with immutability.

I want to decouple the game from the view a little, so I put it in a module and made its update function return a new instance of the world-state, thus providing immutability.

The view (AppControl) is responsible for drawing the world.

However, I see no way around making the world a ref cell in the view.

Now, I think the mutable state is local enough to not cause any problems (please correct me, if I'm wrong), I am just curious, if someone can think of a way to avoid mutable state completely?

Here's the outline of the application, I tried to reduce the problem down to the essence:

```
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open System.Windows.Media

module Game =
    type World = { State : int }

    let init() = 
        { State = 0 }

    // immutable update loop
    let updateWorld world = 
        { State = world.State + 1 }


type AppControl() =
    inherit UserControl()

    let canvas = new Canvas()
    let textBlock = new TextBlock()
    let world = Game.init() |> ref // mutable world

    let drawWorld (world : Game.World) = 
        textBlock.Text <- world.State.ToString()

    // mutating game loop
    let gameLoop world = 
        world := Game.updateWorld !world
        drawWorld !world
        ()

    do  
        canvas.Children.Add(textBlock)
        base.Content <- canvas
        CompositionTarget.Rendering.Add (fun _ -> gameLoop world)


type App() as this =
    inherit Application()
    let main = new AppControl()
    do this.Startup.Add(fun _ -> this.RootVisual <- main)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The structure of your code looks fine - the mutable state is localized in the user interface (which is mutable anyway), so it is fine. You're not mutating the field from any closure, so you could use a mutable field (declared using `let mutable world = ..`) instead of `ref` cell.

To completely avoid the mutation, you can use asynchronous workflow (running on the GUI thread):

```
type AppControl() =
    inherit UserControl()

    let canvas = new Canvas()
    let textBlock = new TextBlock()

    let drawWorld (world : Game.World) = 
        textBlock.Text <- world.State.ToString()

    // Asynchronous loop that waits for 'Rendering', updates
    // the world & draws it and then continues waiting
    let gameLoop world = async {
        let! _ = Async.AwaitEvent CompositionTarget.Rendering
        let newWorld = Game.updateWorld world
        drawWorld newWorld 
        return! gameLoop newWorld }

    do  
        canvas.Children.Add(textBlock)
        base.Content <- canvas
        gameLoop Game.init() |> Async.StartImmediate
```

The `gameLoop` function is asynchronous, so it doesn't block any thread. It is started using `Async.StartImmediate`, which means that it will run only on GUI thread (so accessing GUI elements & events from the body is safe). Inside the function, you can wait for event occurrence (using `Async.AwaitEvent`) and then do some action. The last line (`return!`) is a tail-call, so the function will continue running until the application is closed.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks a lot! I was planning to use an asynchronous workflow for input handling (as I learned from your book, which is _really_ good, by the way!), but it didn't occur to me to use it for updating the state as well.

Comment: I'm kinda new to F#, in your example, does `let! _` have a special meaning or could you get away with a `do!` ?

Comment: @R0MANARMY @bknotic You actually have to use `let! _ = ` when the function you're calling returns some result. `do!` can be used only for asynchronous workflows without return value (`Async<unit>`). So, `do! ...` is shorthand for `let! () = ...`.